# Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

Tags: c++

Описывая `Window.h` столкнулся с проблемой. в приватных полях у меня лежит `m_resizeable` а в публичном метод `IsResize()`. Когда пытаюсь изменить значение `m_resizeable`, ide выводит ошибку на строке `m_isresize = false;`:

> Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

Код приведу ниже:

```
public:
    {...}
    bool IsResize() const { 
        bool tmp = m_isresize;
        m_isresize = false;
        return tmp;
    }
    {...}

private:
    {...}
    bool m_isresize;
};
```

Интересен тот факт, что если поменять знак `=` на `==` то ошибка исчезает, вместе с желаемым результатом

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Метод `IsResize` у тебя объявлен как `const` это означает, что внутри этого метода нельзя менять члены класса. Чтоб можно было изменять член класса внутри константных методов, можно объявить его с квалификатором `mutable`, в твоем случае это так: `mutable bool m_isresize`.
2. Когда ты меняшь = на ==, ты меняешь смысл `присвой` на `сравни`. Присвоение меняет данные в отличае от сравнения, поэтому во втором случае у тебя не возникает ошибки компиляции.

Comment: Только `mutable` нужно использовать крайне редко, и случай из вопроса явно не входит в этот список. @Денис Сунагатов, менять что-либо в константном методе не лучшая идея, за такое Вас вряд ли поблагодарят коллеги.

Comment: Про присвоение я вкурсе, сложно однако перейти с Java на С++. Коллег у меня нет, но спасибо за ответ

Comment: Будущий Вы - коллега настоящему